# How to filter out all data frames (eg. list elements) which don't have a single value of "VALUE1" in the column "Z" in a list of data frames?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, filter

I have a list of few thousand data frames, and about ~95% of those data frames have the required information for me to run a specific script for them. However, in my list of data frames, there are a dozen data frames that are missing this one specific value in the column Z for me to run a script for them, so I want to filter those data frames out of the list completely. Here's a quick example of what I mean:

```
> head(list_of_df[[1]])
# A tibble: 6 × 4
    A     B    Z                                                                        id
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                                                   <int>
1  27.3 0.485 "{\"type\":\"M\",\"msg\":\"VALUE0\",\}"                                     1
2  27.4 0.457  NA                                                                         1
3  27.5 0.430  NA                                                                         1
4  27.6 0.402  NA                                                                         1
5  27.7 0.374  "{\"type\":\"M\",\"msg\":\"VALUE1\",\}"                                    1
6  27.8 0.347  NA                                                                         1
```

The above minimal datasheet has "VALUE1" at some point in the Z column, so this data frame is OK. However if there would not be any instances of "VALUE1" in the Z column in a data frame X, then that data frame X would be filtered out. How can I do this in R?

As a *bonus question*, how could I filter out all the data frames from a list of data frames, that don't have the matching number of rows with "VALUE0" and "VALUE1" in the Z column..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
list_of_df <- list_of_df[which(lapply(list_of_df, function(x) sum(grepl("VALUE1", x$Z))) > 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting "Error in is.factor(x) : object 'Z' not found" if I try to run the block?

Comment: Do all of the list items have a column named 'Z'?

Comment: Yes, they should have.

Comment: Oops, I see that my solution wasn't written for tibbles. I edited my answer

Comment: Woahh, this worked! Thank you a million times!! \../\../ (Just out of curiosity, for what data type(s) was the earlier solution?)

Comment: I wrote it for a list of data.tables

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing it using `purrr::keep`:

(This uses simulated data where the column to check is `a` and the value to test for is "D")

```r
library(tidyverse)

list_of_dfs <- map(1:20, ~tibble(a = sample(LETTERS, 10),
       b = sample(1:100, 10)))

list_of_dfs %>% 
  keep(~ any(str_detect(.x$a, "D")))

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    a         b
#>    <chr> <int>
#>  1 X        15
#>  2 W        36
#>  3 L        69
#>  4 D        63
#>  5 A        23
#>  6 P        72
#>  7 S        30
#>  8 Q        33
#>  9 B        92
#> 10 C        37
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    a         b
#>    <chr> <int>
#>  1 O        28
#>  2 W        85
#>  3 H        15
#>  4 D        53
#>  5 Y        77
#>  6 S        16
#>  7 C        46
#>  8 E        12
#>  9 F        11
#> 10 M        74
#> 
#> ... etc.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! However similarly, if I try to do this for my data (list_of_df %>% 
  keep(~ any(str_detect(.x$Z, grepl("VALUE1", Z))))) for some reason I get the same: "Error in is.factor(x) : object 'report' not found"-message.

Comment: You don't need `grepl` within `str_detect` (as they do the same thing). So just `str_detect(.x$Z, "VALUE1")`

Comment: Ahh I see! I tried this one, but seems like now I get "Error in `.f()`:
! Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a missing value". I tried "VALUE0" instead of "VALUE1" and it returned me basically all about 2000 data frames, so at least the "Z"-column itself should be present in all list elements.

Comment: Both `list_of_dfs %>% keep(~ any(str_detect(.x$a, "D")))` and `list_of_dfs %>% keep(~ any(grepl("D", .x$a)))` do exactly the same thing and I can't reproduce the above error with my simulated code. Glad other solution has worked alright though!